# moving WordPress over to domain, after working on it locally through MAMP

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I've finished the styling changes on WordPress and I'm ready to move it from MAMP to my domain.

Will this involve any changes to the WordPress files or can I just drag it over to my new domain once I purchased it?

Comment: ps - are you OK moving the sql, or do you need help on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main start you must make is update your wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.mynewdomain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.mynewdomain.com');
```

That way wordpress knows what domain it MUST run from.

The reason you do that is because without this you may not be able to access admin, login, etc etc.

When this is working and you have logged in, go to wp-admin and go to your permalink settings.

Make a NOTE of your settings, then change them to default (and woocommerce settings etc).

Go to your home page and a few others, and notice how messed up your urls look :)

Now go back to permalink settings and restore them (the point of this is to make sure your .htaccess file that wordpress depends upon is set correctly)

Finally, have a look at https://github.com/veloper/WordPress-Domain-Changer to change your sql etc if needed.

note this method is very handy for developers so you just update your wp-config.php for localhost or development or production (not for testing purposes, don't use your local pc.  copy it all up to a subdirectory of your hosting partner e.g. http://www.mynewdomain.com/mytestarea.  Make sure you use a COPY of the mysql database (never point both to the same database).  You now can test on the hosting platform without disturbing the live site or your development causing issues to other people.

Comment: ps - if you are using MAMP, have a look at vagrant! So much better to run your environment from a virtual linux server (probably Ubuntu if you are using a virtual host like Digital Ocean, and Centos if using AWS)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long while for me personally, but you'll want to change the SiteURL via the options menu in wp-admin.

Otherwise, just make sure your MySQL database is exported over, your credentials and user permissions are all setup and those work too.

If you still have problems:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL
https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

The database has to be updated. What always works for me is that I export the database from phpMyAdmin or MySQL (using [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)) and open the exported `.sql`-file with a text editor, like Sublime Text.

Now you want to find any occurence of your previous URL. Let's say on your dev machine the URL to the *index* of your Wordpress site is `http://localhost:8080/wordpress` and you want it to be on a website under `https://domain.com` you simply do a `Find & Replace` using that and replace everything with `https://domain.com`.

For older Wordpress versions you have to update the `.htaccess` files if you have custom URL's.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a search replace in your database and replace your local domain ( test.lo ) with the live domain ( test.com ).
To do this you can use the script from here: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/
Add the searchreplacedb2.php file in your route folder and the access test.lo/searchreplacedb2.php and follow the steps there. This will replace your local domain with your live one everywhere in the database.

You can't make a simple search-replace because the local domain might be serialized in some fields in the database, and a simple search-replace will not replace those.